# How to retrieve principal information from HttpSessionEvent in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

I am using the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` class to listen for session changes in my Spring Boot applciation

```
public interface HttpSessionListener extends EventListener {
    default void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }

    default void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I retrieve user information from `HttpSessionEvent`?

I want to delete all the files uploaded by the user after session destroy, that's why I need at least his ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Spring Security stores the `SecurityContext` in the session under the key defined by `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY`. So, if the user is still logged in, you could do:

```java
@Override
void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    HttpSession session = se.getSession();
    SecurityContext context = (SecurityContext) session.getAttribute
        (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
    Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
    // drill down from here, but could be authentication.getName()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide also a link to the documentation for this part please?

Comment: I don't believe this is identified specifically in the documentation, though you might consider opening a ticket - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/new - to discuss the potential of adding this information to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get session by the httpEvent object and from session you can get current user info

se.getSession()

Comment: `se.getSession()` return a `StandardHttpSessionFacade` object, which in turn contains a field `session` that is of type `StandardSession`, but the problem is that the field is private, and I can't get it